Function properties and derivatives
Let $f$ be a thrice differentiable decreasing function of $x>0$. If
$$2[f'']^2 - f'f''' >0$$
where $f'(x) = d f(x)/dx$, what can we say about $f$?

I tried to look at a convex/concave function ($f''>0$) and see what the inequality implies, but could not reach any reasonable answer.


Pose $g=f'$. Then $(1/g)'' = \frac {2g'^2-gg''} {g^3}$. This should allow to prove that when $f$ is increasing (resp. decreasing), $1/f'$ is convex (resp. concave).

We observe that
$$D\left(\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}\right)=\frac{(f^{(2)})^2-f^{(1)}f^{(3)}}{(f^{(2)})^2}>-1$$
So that
$$\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}-\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)>-x$$
And so
$$\int_0^x \frac{f^{(2)}}{f^{(1)}}dt<\int_0^x\frac{1}{-t+\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)}dt$$
And
$$log\left(f^{(1)}\right)-log\left(f^{(1)}(0)\right)<-log\left(\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)-x\right)+log\left(\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)\right)$$
Let us continue
$$f^{(1)}<e^{log(f^{(1)}(0))-log\left(\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)-x\right)+log\left(\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)\right)}$$
$$f^{(1)}<f^{(1)}(0)\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)-x}\cdot\frac{f^{(1)}}{f^{(2)}}(0)=\frac{(f^{(1)}(0))^2}{f^{(1)}(0)-f^{(2)}(0)x}$$
Finally
$$f(x)-f(0)<-\frac{(f^{(1)}(0))^2}{f^{(2)}(0)} log\left( f^{(1)}(0)-f^{(2)}(0)x\right)+\frac{(f^{(1)}(0))^2}{f^{(2)}(0)} log\left( f^{(1)}(0)\right)=\frac{(f^{(1)}(0))^2}{f^{(2)}(0)}log\left( \frac{f^{(1)}(0)}{f^{(1)}(0)-f^{(2)}(0)x}\right)$$
Thus
$$f(x)<f(0)+\frac{(f^{(1)}(0))^2}{f^{(2)}(0)}log\left( \frac{f^{(1)}(0)}{f^{(1)}(0)-f^{(2)}(0)x}\right).$$
